# What does MSL do in the ARM instruction MOVI <Vd>.<T> #<imm8>, MSL #amount

Tags: assembly, arm, arm64, armv8, capstone

I am confused about the operation MSL, which is used in a variant of the MOVI and MVNI instructions.

There's not a lot of information out there, but I have seen it referred to as "Masking Shift Left". Could anyone give an example of what a masking shift is? The instruction variant is also described as "shifting ones variant". I am not sure what this means either.

https://developer.arm.com/documentation/dui0801/c/A64-SIMD-Vector-Instructions/MOVI--vector-

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Running `movi v0.4s, #32, msl #8` through gdb shows `v0` containing `{0x20FF, 0x20FF, 0x20FF, 0x20FF}`, implying that MSL shifts to the left but pads in with 1's rather than 0's

In binary:
32 would be `00100000`
shifting left 8 places padding in 1's gives `0010000011111111` which is `20FF` in hex

The same is true with a negative immediate, with `movi v1.4s #-32, msl #8` giving `{0xE0FF, 0xE0FF, 0xE0FF, 0xE0FF}`

Answer (score 2):

“Shifting ones” means that the bit positions where nothing is shifted to are set to 1. In a “logical shift”, or generally in a “shift” without explicit qualification, those bit positions are set to 0.

Demo (with 64-bit code):

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main() {
    unsigned long v0u, v0l, v1u, v1l, v2u, v2l;
    asm (
        "movi v0.4s, #42\n"
        "mov %[v0u], v0.d[0]\n"
        "mov %[v0l], v0.d[1]\n"
        "movi v1.4s, #42, lsl #8\n"
        "mov %[v1u], v1.d[0]\n"
        "mov %[v1l], v1.d[1]\n"
        "movi v2.4s, #42, msl #8\n"
        "mov %[v2u], v2.d[0]\n"
        "mov %[v2l], v2.d[1]\n"
        : [v0u] "=r" (v0u), [v0l] "=r" (v0l),
          [v1u] "=r" (v1u), [v1l] "=r" (v1l),
          [v2u] "=r" (v2u), [v2l] "=r" (v2l)
        :
        : "v0");
    printf("plain  : %016lx%016lx\n", v0u, v0l);
    printf("lsl #8 : %016lx%016lx\n", v1u, v1l);
    printf("msl #8 : %016lx%016lx\n", v2u, v2l);
}
```

Output:

```
plain  : 0000002a0000002a0000002a0000002a
lsl #8 : 00002a0000002a0000002a0000002a00
msl #8 : 00002aff00002aff00002aff00002aff
```

I can't find this documented in the assembler manual. It is documented in the [Architecture Reference Manual](https://developer.arm.com/documentation/ddi0487/latest) if you care to dig through it (references for version DDI0487H.a):

- C7.2.204 `MOVI` p.2490: “shifting ones” is `cmode == 110x`.
- `AdvSIMDExpandImm` p.11185: `Zeros(X):imm8:Ones(8)` where `X` is either 8 or 16.